# ArcGIS Javascript, add headarrow in the end of line?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, svg, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-online-basemaps

Ok so I'm planning to add arrow in the last coordinate point.

```
 var line = new Polyline(wgs84);
          var b = 0; 
          var a = 0;
             // console.log(hasilarray);
          arrayUtils.forEach(hasilarray, function(ple){
            // console.log();
            if(a==0){
              var jumlah = akhir.length;
              for(c=0;c<jumlah;c++){
                var load = JSON.stringify(hasilarray[0][c]);
                console.log(load +" jalur "+c);
                var jumlah_k = hasilarray[0][c].length;
                for(d=0;d<jumlah_k;d++){
                  // array_koordinat.push(hasilarray[0][c][d]);
                  var koor_x_p = hasilarray[1][d][0].toString();
                  var koor_y_p = hasilarray[1][d][1].toString();
                  var x_ = Number(koor_x_p);
                  var y_ = Number(koor_y_p);
                  array_koordinat.push(x_,y_);
                  koordinat_a.push(array_koordinat);
                  array_koordinat=[];
                }
                line.addPath(hasilarray[0][c]);
              }
            }else{
              var load = JSON.stringify(hasilarray[1]);
              // console.log(JSON.stringify(hasilarray[1]));
              //console.log(load +" jalur terakhir");
              var jumlah_k = hasilarray[1].length;
              for(e=0;e<jumlah_k;e++){
                  var koor_x_p = hasilarray[1][e][0].toString();
                  var koor_y_p = hasilarray[1][e][1].toString();
                  var x_ = Number(koor_x_p);
                  var y_ = Number(koor_y_p);
                  array_koordinat.push(x_,y_);
                  koordinat_a.push(array_koordinat);
                  array_koordinat=[];
                }
              // array_koordinat.push(hasilarray[1]);
              line.addPath(hasilarray[1]);

            }
            a++;
            b++;
          }) ;
```

You can get the coordinate by get koordinat_a array (example: koordinat_a[0], you'll get the value of x and y coordinate.

I'm not so familiar with javascript and arcgis, but I'll try everything.

How could I add some arrow to last point? I've been looking couple days but all of them is dekstop GIS.

Edit: I've found it, take a look to my answer, maybe someone need it.

Comment: The current version of the API doesn't support arrowheads. You would have to add a separate point graphic at the endpoint with an arrowhead appropriately rotated.

Comment: Hi @BjornSvensson I've found how to add arrowheads. Surely isn't official from the API itself, but we can made some trick of them. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking for arrow in the end of line, you can check this modified [DirectionalLineSymbol](https://github.com/nickcam/DirectionalLineSymbol) js. Thanks to nickcam for his work.

It's makes you can add arrow along the line path OR you can call the end head arrow only. It's also contain animate arrow, so feel free to modified it! (But don't forget to credit Nick for his great work).

[image: Nick Arrow Head]